# Creating overlapping boarder colours with xlsxwriter and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

Given the following data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=(6, 5)),
    columns=["X", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
    index=["a", "b", "X", "d", "e", "X"],
)
```

I can create a xlsx file with formatted boarders using the following:

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter("testing.xlsx") as writer:
    #  need to create xlsx output for this example
    sheet_name = "Sheet1"
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    # create horizontal line
    row_range = (3, 3)
    col_range = (1, 8)
    worksheet.conditional_format(
        row_range[0],
        col_range[0],
        row_range[1],
        col_range[1],
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "top": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )
    # create vertical line
    row_range = (1, 9)
    col_range = (4, 4)
    worksheet.conditional_format(
        row_range[0],
        col_range[0],
        row_range[1],
        col_range[1],
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "left": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )
```

However the formatting is incorrect (or, not as desired), and looks as:

[image]

The part which is incorrect is:

[image]

It seems that I am unable to format a cell twice? Which is an issue here.

This question might generalise from creating an overlapping boarder to creating overlapping conditional formatting, I'm not familiar enough with xlsxwriter to say.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the workaround cause it seems like a bug and I'm not an author of the module.

The idea is to not let the cells to overlap. I split the 2 ranges into 5 ranges. The cell which lies at the crossroad has coloured 2 borders.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=(6, 5)),
    columns=["X", "a", "b", "c", "d"],
    index=["a", "b", "X", "d", "e", "X"],
)

with pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\kemot\\Desktop\\programy Python\\testing.xlsx") as writer:
    #  need to create xlsx output for this example
    sheet_name = "Sheet1"
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

 
   # create horizontal line
    worksheet.conditional_format(
        'A4:B4',
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "bottom": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )

    worksheet.conditional_format(
        'C4',
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "right": 2,
                    "bottom": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )

    worksheet.conditional_format(
        'D4:F4',
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "bottom": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )
    # create vertical line

    worksheet.conditional_format(
        'D1:D3',
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "left": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )

    worksheet.conditional_format(
        'D5:D10',
        {
            "type": "no_errors",
            "format": workbook.add_format(
                {
                    "left": 2,
                    "border_color": "red",
                }
            ),
        },
    )
```

Comment: cheers, i think i'd need a way to generalise this in order for it to be a solution.

Comment: I argue that it's a bug. Are you of different opinion?

Comment: Yeah this might be considered a bug, i'm not sure if it's an excel limitation or an xlsxwriter limitation though ( I dont' know either well enough). By general I meant that it would be better if there was a function which could take in lines and handle the intersections.